# MS Word: Replace variable length string

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am working on a macro to replace a string of variable length.

For example:
I have to search for strings in a Word document starting with -$ followed by a number. It can be -$10 billion or -$123456 or -$189.90 million. This should be replaced with ($10) billion, ($123456) and ($189.90) million.

I can replace "-" by finding .Text = "-$[0-9]".

How do I put ")" at the end of the each number found.

Comment: Add the language tag.

Comment: Hobbs- it's VBA, I'm trying to write find a way to create build the macro on word.

Comment: Yu Hao - Thank you for the help, Can you please explain more I very new to macros and not very technical person.